# Rotate SkSpriteNode around internal point that is not .anchorPoint

Tags: swift, rotation, sprite-kit, sprite

So I'm using this code to rotate an object either clockwise or anti-clockwise.

```
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let touchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let newRotationDirection : rotationDirection = touchPosition.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) ? .clockwise : .counterClockwise

    if currentRotationDirection != newRotationDirection && currentRotationDirection != .none {
        reverseRotation()
        currentRotationDirection = newRotationDirection
    }
    else if (currentRotationDirection == .none) {
        setupRotationWith(direction: newRotationDirection)
        currentRotationDirection = newRotationDirection
    }
}



func reverseRotation(){
    let oldRotateAction = ship.actionForKey("rotate")
    let newRotateAction = SKAction.reversedAction(oldRotateAction!)
    ship.runAction(newRotateAction(), withKey: "rotate")
}



func stopRotation(){
    ship.removeActionForKey("rotate")
}



func setupRotationWith(direction direction: rotationDirection){
    let angle : CGFloat = (direction == .clockwise) ? CGFloat(M_PI) : -CGFloat(M_PI)
    let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(angle, duration: 2)
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotate)
    ship.runAction(repeatAction, withKey: "rotate")
}
```

My question is, this creates clockwise or anticlockwise rotation around the SKSpriteNode's anchor point.

However I would like the object to rotate about another point inside of the SKSprite (something like 4/5's of the way up from the base of the sprite image). I assume I cannot use a set point defined through CGPointMake as I would like the sprite to independently move around the screen and this would not work?

Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `anchorPoint` property of your sprite to the point around which you want the sprite to rotate?

```
ship.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 4/5)
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately this causes my sprite to entirely disappear?

Comment: Oups, how stupid of me: anchorPoint goes from 0 to 1, so using 4/5 is the right way... Sorry! (I've already corrected my answer.)

Comment: Aaaaand that has completely worked, awesome thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome! :)  Please, feel free to chose my answer as correct (yes, I only help for the glory). ;P

Comment: Done, I'd be the exact same! (If I was in the position to give advice haha)